# RT5370 link is not ready

Tags: wifi, wlan

I am trying to add an RT5370 dongle (RA-WN110606C) to my Raspi CM3+.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to make it work. I can see the WLAN appear when I execute ifconfig :

```
wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:12:01:a2:43:84  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

But I cannot connect to an AP neither do a scan. Here is the problem.

dmesg:

```
[ 1770.256083] ieee80211 phy7: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 5390, rev 0502 detected
[ 1770.283323] ieee80211 phy7: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 5370 detected
[ 1770.284066] ieee80211 phy7: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[ 1770.448300] ieee80211 phy7: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2870.bin'
[ 1770.448369] ieee80211 phy7: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.36
[ 1770.732480] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 1772.307221] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 1772.676753] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 1775.361051] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 1775.692278] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

I keep having this message and never have the message "IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready"

Do you have any solution that I can try to resolve this problem with this dongle

Answer (score 0):

Here is some new log that I got on a Raspi 3B+. It still doesn't work but it's different...

```
May 17 14:25:37 raspberrypi kernel: [ 7843.980834] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
May 17 14:25:37 raspberrypi kernel: [ 7844.128434] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=5370, bcdDevice= 1.01
May 17 14:25:37 raspberrypi kernel: [ 7844.128453] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
May 17 14:25:37 raspberrypi kernel: [ 7844.128463] usb 1-1.4: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
May 17 14:25:37 raspberrypi kernel: [ 7844.128472] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Ralink
May 17 14:25:37 raspberrypi kernel: [ 7844.128481] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 1.0
May 17 14:25:37 raspberrypi kernel: [ 7844.220847] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
May 17 14:25:38 raspberrypi kernel: [ 7844.361606] ieee80211 phy2: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 5390, rev 0502 detected
May 17 14:25:38 raspberrypi kernel: [ 7844.388994] ieee80211 phy2: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 5370 detected
May 17 14:25:38 raspberrypi kernel: [ 7844.412862] ieee80211 phy2: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
May 17 14:25:38 raspberrypi kernel: [ 7844.616936] ieee80211 phy2: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2870.bin'
May 17 14:25:38 raspberrypi kernel: [ 7844.619883] ieee80211 phy2: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.36
May 17 14:25:38 raspberrypi kernel: [ 7844.902145] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan1: link is not ready
May 17 14:25:39 raspberrypi kernel: [ 7846.193128] wlan1: authenticate with 18:31:bf:04:73:00
May 17 14:25:39 raspberrypi kernel: [ 7846.224845] wlan1: send auth to 18:31:bf:04:73:00 (try 1/3)
May 17 14:25:39 raspberrypi kernel: [ 7846.259322] wlan1: send auth to 18:31:bf:04:73:00 (try 2/3)
May 17 14:25:39 raspberrypi kernel: [ 7846.300321] wlan1: send auth to 18:31:bf:04:73:00 (try 3/3)
May 17 14:25:39 raspberrypi kernel: [ 7846.351243] wlan1: authentication with 18:31:bf:04:73:00 timed out
May 17 14:25:41 raspberrypi kernel: [ 7847.703600] wlan1: authenticate with 18:31:bf:04:73:00
May 17 14:25:41 raspberrypi kernel: [ 7847.732942] wlan1: send auth to 18:31:bf:04:73:00 (try 1/3)
May 17 14:25:41 raspberrypi kernel: [ 7847.751929] wlan1: send auth to 18:31:bf:04:73:00 (try 2/3)
May 17 14:25:41 raspberrypi kernel: [ 7847.790716] wlan1: send auth to 18:31:bf:04:73:00 (try 3/3)
May 17 14:25:41 raspberrypi kernel: [ 7847.838311] wlan1: authentication with 18:31:bf:04:73:00 timed out
```